# Error while using v4 Java SDK dependency to connect to CosmosDB

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-cosmos</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

While using above dependency I am getting following error -

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Cosmosdb' defined in class path resource [com/walmart/dna/sourcing/jdbc/config/CosmosConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClient]: Factory method 'cosmosClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClient]: Factory method 'cosmosClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:76) ~[azure-cosmos-4.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.<clinit>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:100) ~[azure-cosmos-4.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.AsyncDocumentClient$Builder.build(AsyncDocumentClient.java:207) ~[azure-cosmos-4.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosAsyncClient.<init>(CosmosAsyncClient.java:102) ~[azure-cosmos-4.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(CosmosClientBuilder.java:699) ~[azure-cosmos-4.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClient.<init>(CosmosClient.java:30) ~[azure-cosmos-4.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClientBuilder.buildClient(CosmosClientBuilder.java:711) ~[azure-cosmos-4.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.walmart.dna.sourcing.jdbc.config.CosmosConfiguration.cosmosClient(CosmosConfiguration.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.walmart.dna.sourcing.jdbc.config.CosmosConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$682f48b.CGLIB$cosmosClient$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.walmart.dna.sourcing.jdbc.config.CosmosConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$682f48b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e4ee6466.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.walmart.dna.sourcing.jdbc.config.CosmosConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$682f48b.cosmosClient(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Comment: @user11725513 did you solve it? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @VivekVardhan No didnt find solution for it, I used older dependency azure-documentdb to work with it